# Configuring setcifsacl to use local posix user instead of SID for CIFS share on Linux

Tags: linux, cifs, webdav

I have a CIFS filesystem (from a NetAPP) mounted on a Red Hat 6 server using cifs_utils, and am sharing some directories from the CIFS filesystem out over HTTPS via WebDAV.  I need to set some ACLs on the directories so that the local Apache user can access the files on behalf of the users who are accessing the share via WebDAV, but when trying to use setcifsacl from the cifs_utils package, it seems to expect an SID, and doesn't recognize the user apache, or the apache user UID (48).  The man page doesn't give much information.  Any suggestions?  I am mounting the CIFS mount RW already.

Mounting with the cifsacl option actually makes things worse, as files are stripped of all permissions (ls -la shows --------- for a file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a very simple and ineloquent solution of uid=apache,gid=apache in the mount options, which nullifies the need for ACLs for the apache user.